# std::initializer_list as template argument for constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, initializer-list, type-deduction

Consider a class which inherits from a std container with a template constructor which calls the underlying constructor of the container. This template constructor works for the simple copy and move constructor but not for the initializer_list ctor.

```cpp
template<typename container_T>
class test : public container_T {
public:
  using container_type = container_T;

  test() {} 

  // templated constructor
  template<typename T>
  test(T t)
    : container_T(t) {}

   // without this it won't compile
  test(std::initializer_list<typename container_T::value_type> l)
    : container_T(l) {}
};

int main() {    
  test<std::deque<int>> vdi1;
  test<std::deque<int>> vdi2({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9});

  std::cout << "vdi2 before:" << std::endl;
  for(auto it : vdi2)
    std::cout << it << std::endl;

  test<std::deque<int>> vdi3(std::move(vdi2));

  std::cout << "vdi2 before:" << std::endl;
  for(auto it : vdi2)
    std::cout << it << std::endl;

  std::cout << "vdi3 before:" << std::endl;
  for(auto it : vdi3)
    std::cout << it << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

If I remove the `initializer_list` constructor `vdi2` won't compile. So my question: Why is the initializer_list not deduced by the template constructor? And is it possible to do so?

Comment: Actually, it is not a copy or move, they're declared implicitly, in addition to your ctor. And it doesn't work for `initializer_list`s as they cannot be/are not deduced.

Comment: Why don't you use inheriting ctors? `using container_T::container_T;` [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/723b9da6b0f8766f)

Comment: @DyP why should itinherit copy or move ctors?

Comment: Edited comment (.. still a word missing: _Actually, it is not a copy or move _ctor__). What I meant was: a ctor template is never a copy or move ctor.

Comment: @DyP actually... `using container_T::container_T;` is exactly what i was searching for. i've forgotten the possibility of inheriting constructors. thx

Comment: Looks like you wanna read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733828/initializing-from-an-initializer-list-but-without

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> > why is the initializer_list not deduced by the templated constructor?

The reason is that `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` is just a synctatic construct that doesn't have a type. Therefore, the compiler cannot deduce a type `T` for this synctatic construct and the first constructor fails.

However, by special Standard rules `std::initializer_list<T>` (among other things) can be construct from this synctatic construct and `T` can be deduced to `int`. Hence the second constructor works.

By constrast with function template argument type deduction, with

```
auto x = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
```

the compiler sets the type of x to be `std::initializer_list<int>`. There are also special Standard rules that says it must be so. Strictly speaking this is *not* type deduction because, as said above, `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}` doesn't have a type to be deduced. (The only type deduction happening here is `T = int` in `std::initializer_list<T>`.) Here the compiler chooses (it doesn't deduce) the type of `x` to be `std::initializer_list<int>`. In any case, there's no harm to use the abuse of language of saying that the type of `x` is deduced to `std::initializer_list<int>`.

Finally, as DyP said in the comments, what you probably want is inheriting all constructors (not only those taking one argument) from the base container class. You can do this by removing all the constructors that you currently have and add just this line to `test`:

```
using container_type::container_type;
```